# C# Ado.net, Error: "There was an error parsing the query."

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am writing a program in C# using Visual Studio 2010 and gets an error when retrieving data from a .sdf-file.

Here follow the code of the class retrieving data from the database:

//DataAccess.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
/// <summary>
/// Demonstrates how to work with SqlConnection objects
/// </summary>

    namespace GameDAL
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Serve as main database layer.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        public class DataAccess
        {
            SqlCeConnection conn = null;
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            // 3. Pass the connection to a command object
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            string strConnection =null;
            string dbfile =null;
            string TABLE_NAME = "Statistics";
            string conString;
            /// <summary>
            /// Initialise connection and connection string
            /// </summary>
            public DataAccess()
            {
                InitConnection();
            }

            public void InitConnection()
            {
                // Create a connection to the file Statistics.sdf in the program folder
                MessageBox.Show("test new reflection");
                dbfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\Statistics.sdf";
                MessageBox.Show("test time new conn");

                conn = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile);
                MessageBox.Show("test before opening");

                conn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("test before new connectionstr");
                conString = Properties.Settings.Default.StatisticsConnectionString;

                if (conn == null)
                   MessageBox.Show("warning connis null !!!!!");

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Returns connection to database.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public SqlCeConnection GetConnection()
            {
                return conn;
            }

            /// <summary>
            ///                     /// Write one row to database containing winner name ,winner score and, winner nr of cards.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="winnerName">Name of winner</param>
            /// <param name="winnerScore">Score of winner</param>
            /// <param name="winnerNrOfCards"></param>
            public void WriteDataToDatabase(string winnerName, int winnerScore, int winnerNrOfCards )
            {

                // Retrieve the connection string from the settings file


                // Open the connection using the connection string.
                using (conn)
                {

                    // Insert into the SqlCe table. ExecuteNonQuery is best for inserts.
                    using (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand com = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO"+TABLE_NAME + "VALUES(@winnerName, @winnerScore, @winnerNrOfCards)", conn))
                    {
                        com.Connection = conn;
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@winnerName", winnerName);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@winnerScore", winnerScore);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@winnerNumberOfcards", winnerNrOfCards);
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Read data from database.
            /// Put data in array list with DataFromDatabase-instances, containing the stats for each game.
            /// <returns>Returns arrayList with all data of database..</returns>

            public List<DataFromDatabase> ReadAllDataFromDataBase()
            {
                string winnerName;
                int winnerScore;
                int winnerNrOfCards;

                if (conn == null)
                    InitConnection();

                //System.Collections.ArrayList arrayListWithStatsFromDatabase= new System.Collections.ArrayList ();
                List<DataFromDatabase> dataFromDatabaseList = new List<DataFromDatabase> ();
                SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT winnerName, winnerScore, winnerNumberOfCards FROM Statistics");
                MessageBox.Show("Now we inside ReadAllData and will be using conn");

                if (conn == null)
                    MessageBox.Show("warning connis null !!!!! before using CONN");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("conn is " + conn);
                using (conn)
                {
                    // Read in all values in the table.
                    MessageBox.Show("conn OK.. comm is" + com);

                    //("SELECT * FROM"+ TABLE_NAME, conn);         
                    using (com)
                    {
                        com.Connection = conn;
                        MessageBox.Show("Now we inside ReadAllData and will be using reader..");
                        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                        MessageBox.Show("Now we inside ReadAllData and..after exec reader reader..");
                        //Add data from each row in table of database.
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            winnerName = reader.GetString(0);
                            winnerScore = reader.GetInt32(1);
                            winnerNrOfCards = reader.GetInt32(2);
                            dataFromDatabaseList.Add(new DataFromDatabase(winnerName, winnerScore, winnerNrOfCards));
                        }

                    } //end of using

                } //end of using 2

                return dataFromDatabaseList;
            } //end of methods

        } //end of class
    } //end of namespace..
```

//Database table:
Statistics.sdf

Table name: Statistics
Columns: winnerName, winnerScore,winnerNumberOfCards

The bug occurs in this methods:

ReadAllDataFromDatabase() when executing          SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

Error message: '{"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 58,Token in error = Statistics ]"}'

```
Error report:

    System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
      Message=Anropet av konstruktorn av typen BlackJack.MainWindow som matchar de angivna bindningsbegränsningarna utlöste ett undantag. radnummer 4 och radposition 76.
      Source=PresentationFramework
      LineNumber=4
      LinePosition=76
      StackTrace:
           vid System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
           vid System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
           vid System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
           vid System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
           vid System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
           vid System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
           vid System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
           vid System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
           vid System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
           vid MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
           vid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
           vid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
           vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
           vid System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
           vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
           vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           vid System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
           vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
           vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
           vid MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
           vid MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
           vid System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
           vid MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
           vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
           vid MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
           vid MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
           vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
           vid System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
           vid System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
           vid System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
           vid System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
           vid System.Windows.Application.Run()
           vid BlackJack.App.Main() i D:\Programmering\C-sharp Malmö Advancd\BlackJack3\BlackJack\BlackJack\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:rad 0
           vid System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
           vid System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
           vid System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
           vid System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
           vid System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
           vid System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
           vid System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
           vid Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
           vid System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
           vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
           vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
           vid System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
      InnerException: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
           Message=There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 58,Token in error = Statistics ]
           Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
           HResult=-2147217900
           NativeError=25501
           StackTrace:
                vid System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
                vid System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
                vid System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
                vid System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteReader()
                vid GameDAL.DataAccess.ReadAllDataFromDataBase() i D:\Programmering\C-sharp Malmö Advancd\BlackJack3\BlackJack\GameDAL\DataAccess.cs:rad 133
                vid BlackJack.GameManager.ReadInDataFromDatabase() i D:\Programmering\C-sharp Malmö Advancd\BlackJack3\BlackJack\BlackJack\GameManager.cs:rad 660
                vid BlackJack.MainWindow.ResetListANDGUIWithStatisticsAndReadInNewDataFromDatabase() i D:\Programmering\C-sharp Malmö Advancd\BlackJack3\BlackJack\BlackJack\MainWindow.xaml.cs:rad 94
                vid BlackJack.MainWindow..ctor() i D:\Programmering\C-sharp Malmö Advancd\BlackJack3\BlackJack\BlackJack\MainWindow.xaml.cs:rad 71
           InnerException:
```

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Statistics` is a reserved word, escape its name with `[]` notation as `string TABLE_NAME = "[Statistics]"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
string TABLE_NAME = "Statistics";
```

and

```
"INSERT INTO"+TABLE_NAME + "VAL
```

combine those and you get

```
"INSERT INTOStatisticsVAL
```

What you should have is:

```
"INSERT INTO "+TABLE_NAME + " VAL
```

or (better; works for keywords and names with spaces etc):

```
"INSERT INTO ["+TABLE_NAME + "] VAL
```

Comment: Not the error causing the bug above; but thanks for finding a bug!!